# Bootstrap 3 - Is it possible not to collapse navbar, and collapse sidebar to navbar menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make the navbar not to be collapsed, and collapsing the sidebar to the navbar menu.

Currently this is my navbar:

[image]

Currently the menu only uses glyphicons, so I thought it would be a good idea in mobile view not to collapse them inside the navbar push open menu.

In mobile mode:

[image]

The navbar menu items get collapse into the pull down menu.

Currently, this is my html code:

```
<!-- Top Navigation Bar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebStats</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'WebApp:logout'%}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href="{% url 'WebApp:index'%}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></a></li>

                <li><a href="#toggleMenu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-indent-left"></a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-no-collapse="true">
                        <li><a href="{% url 'WebApp:addChart'%}">Add</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'WebApp:editChart'%}">Edit</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#removeChart">Remove</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Middle Navigation Area -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'WebApp:index'%}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span> Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Reports</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Analytics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Export</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li><a href="#simpleShare"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> SimpleShare</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS Code:

```
/*
 * Base structure
 */

/* Move down content because we have a fixed navbar that is 50px tall */
body 
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

/*
 * Global add-ons
 */

.custom-button-length
{
    width: 100px;
}

.sub-header 
{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

/*
 * Top navigation
 * Hide default border to remove 1px line.
 */
@media (max-width: 767px) 
{
    .navbar-fixed-top
    {
        position: relative;
        top: auto;
    }

    .navbar-collapse 
    {
        max-height: none!important;
    }

    body 
    {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar-default 
    {
        max-height: none;
    }
}

/*
 * Sidebar
 */

/* Hide for mobile, show later */
.wrapper 
{
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.wrapper.toggled 
{
    padding-left: 250px;
}

.wrapper.toggled .sidebar 
{
    margin-left: -250px;
}

.sidebar 
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 51px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    transition: all 1.0s ease;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) 
{
    .sidebar 
    {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
}

/* Sidebar navigation */
.nav-sidebar 
{
    margin-right: -21px; /* 20px padding + 1px border */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

.nav-sidebar > li > a 
{
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: fixed-top;
}

.nav-sidebar > .active > a,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:hover,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:focus 
{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #428bca;
}


/*
 * Main content
 */

.main 
{
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 210px;
    margin-top:50px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    transition: all 1.0s ease;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) 
{
    .main 
    {
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: -20px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 1.0s ease;
        -o-transition: all 1.0s ease;
        transition: all 1.0s ease;
    }
}

.main .page-header 
{
    margin-top: 0;
}

.main.toggled
{
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    transition: all 1.0s ease;
}

/*
 *  Panels
 */


.panel-body
{
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

/*
 * Placeholder dashboard ideas
 */

.placeholders 
{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.placeholders h4 
{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.placeholder 
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.placeholder img 
{
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.graph-container
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 850px;
    height: 450px;
    padding: 20px 15px 15px 15px;
    margin: 15px auto 30px auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(#f6f6f6 0, #fff 50px);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f6f6f6 0, #fff 50px);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#f6f6f6 0, #fff 50px);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f6f6f6 0, #fff 50px);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f6f6f6 0, #fff 50px);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.graph-placeholder 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}

.legend table
{
    border-spacing: 5px;
}

/*
 *  Chart Configuration Modal
 */

#chartConfigModal .modal-dialog
{
    width: 800px;/* your width */
}

.wrapper-config
{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

It seems that the key is within:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

But I have trouble to figure out how.

Edit:

With the collapse removed, the sidebar suddenly increases in right around 250 px

[image]

Edit:

Fixed with:

```
.nav.navbar-nav > li
{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: @creimers: Please don't remove the non-version-specific tag (in this case `twitter-bootstrap` when adding a more specific tag (`twitter-bootstrap-3`).  Keep them both as not everyone browses both tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved your navbar issue by removing the navbar-collapse collapse class and removing the collapse button and some css code for the mobile view

HTML

```
    <!-- Top Navigation Bar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebStats</a>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'WebApp:logout'%}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></a></li>
                </ul>
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-middle visible-xs">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'WebApp:logout'%}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></a></li>
            </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a href="{% url 'WebApp:index'%}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></a></li>

                    <li><a href="#toggleMenu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-indent-left"></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list">
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-no-collapse="true">
                            <li><a href="{% url 'WebApp:addChart'%}">Add</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% url 'WebApp:editChart'%}">Edit</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#removeChart">Remove</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS in addition to your css

```
    @media (max-width: 768px) 
    {
    .nav > li
    {
    float:left;
    }
    .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left
    {
    float:left;
    }
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-middle
    {
    float:right;
    }
    .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
    {
    float:right;
    }
    }
```

And for the Sidebar just replace the navbar-middle with the Sidebar-content

Comment: I was thinking maybe to put the sidebar to the pulldown, because the sidebar might get long.